# How to composite images with offsets and scaling into a single image?

Tags: imagemagick, image-processing

I would like to use imagemagick to create a mosaic.

I have a list of images along with their individual offsets and scales, for example:

- a.jpg, translate to 0,0 and scale to 100%
- b.jpg, translate to 200,50 and scale to 25%
- c.jpg, translate to 100,320 and scale to 33%

The idea is to scale/translate the images as indicated and composite them together.

I've tried commands such as `convert a.jpg \(b.jpg -resize 25%\) -geometry +200+50 \(c.jpg -resize 33% \) -geometry +100+320 -composite out.jpg` but the output is cropped to the size of the first image. Since I don't know the dimensions of the images beforehand, I don't know the final extent of the image.

What would be a good way to do this with imagemagick?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737061/merge-images-side-by-side-horizontally

Comment: @Gantendo None of the content in your link is relevant to my question.

Comment: No, I hoped you would rewrite your question to better explain what you want...

Comment: Perhaps you could  create a huge image like e.g. this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787356/use-imagemagick-to-place-an-image-inside-a-larger-canvas then crop it to first non-transparent pixel? (`-trim`)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-mosaic` option to allow compositing outside the boundaries of the original image.

So, create a blue and a red rectangle:

```
magick -size 640x480 xc:blue blue.png
magick -size 100x100 xc:red red.png
```

Now composite the red rectangle onto the blue one, but ***outside*** its original extent and make the background yellow to show where we forced **ImageMagick** to extend the image:

```
magick blue.png -background yellow -page +800+30 red.png -mosaic result.png
```

[image]

---

Also, if you have thousands of images to composite, all listed in a CSV, you would be better to use the CSV to make a *"magick-script"* with all the commands in it so you can do the whole lot in a single invocation, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77318098/2836621) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/721917/400632).